Is there an algorithm to find the closest element to X in an unsorted array in Ω(logN)?
A[i] is the closest element to X if there is no A[j] such that |X-A[j]| < |X-A[i]|.
Well my book says there is an algorithm that could do it because the lower bound of the decision tree is of Ω(logN), but I'm not quite sure how you can find this element without going through all N elements considering that the array is not necessarily sorted.

This may be a trick question. Big-Omega notation is a lower bound. An algorithm that runs in Ω(logN) time takes at least that much time, asymptotically. A straightforward linear search solves this problem in Ω(logN) time.
If you want to solve this problem in O(logN) time, where logN is an asymptotic upper bound, then no, that's impossible.

How does a linear search complete without looking at every element?  Isn't that Ω(N) almost by definition?

@MarkRansom: A program that takes Ω(N) time also takes Ω(logN) time.

Perhaps I just don't understand Big-Omega, but I don't see how a linear search could ever finish in logN time.

@MarkRansom: N is asymptotically at least logN, so Ω(logN) is a valid lower bound on the program's runtime. Lower bounds don't have to be good to be valid.

So wouldn't Ω(1) be just as accurate?  And be valid for every single algorithm?

@MarkRansom You usually want a more strict lower bound so that you can use big theta to convey more information where applicable.

@Unmitigated which is why I claim Ω(N) is a better answer than Ω(logN) for the linear search.  If I'm wrong, please help me understand why.

@MarkRansom: It looks like the purpose of the exercise was probably to demonstrate decision tree bounds, rather than to actually produce a good lower bound for the runtime of algorithms that solve this search problem. We do usually prefer tighter bounds over less tight bounds, but Ω(logN) is what computing a decision tree bound gives for this problem, and it's still a valid bound.

Yes, I thought the same thing, but it was still weird to me since I hadn't seen any "trick questions" like this in this book which is why it seemed kind of unusual to me.

Your answer states "A straightforward linear search solves this problem in Ω(logN) time" which is what I didn't understand.  What you're saying is that even though a linear search would never be that fast, the statement is still true because it would never be slower than that.

@MarkRansom No, it's because it's not faster than that.

No, of course not. As you noted, any algorithm will need to examine all elements of the array. (Consider if your algorithm knows that the array is one of 100 possible arrays, where each one is identical except for a single element, that element being the closest element. There would be no way for any algorithm to determine the answer without looking at all 100 elements, in the worst case.)
It is possible that the textbook meant to say "sorted". (Or, as user\d+ said, they're being exceedingly gotcha-y with their use of big-omega.)
